# Verification of number of Sperner Families for n=3

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

According to Wikipedia:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner_family,
the number of Sperner families for $n=3$ ought to be 20.

However, it seems I can only find 17.

Is the empty set $\{\}$ included? Even if so, that makes it 18?

Thanks for helping me find the last two.

The 17 I found:

```
{{1}}
{{2}}
{{3}}
{{1,2}}
{{1,3}}
{{2,3}}
{{1,2,3}}
{{1},{2}}
{{1},{3}}
{{2},{3}}
{{1},{2,3}}
{{2},{1,3}}
{{3},{1,2}}
{{1,2},{1,3}}
{{1,2},{2,3}}
{{1,3},{2,3}}
{{1,2},{1,3},{2,3}}
```

Update: I found one more {{1},{2},{3}}. The last one eludes me.

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed missing the empty set $\{\}$, as well as the set $\{\{\}\}$ containing only the empty set.